# Movilizer - Erase masterdata pool, is this possible?

Tags: mobile, movilizer

I know I can delete all the keys from a masterdata pool.

But is it possible to remove the pool itself forever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this is possible. But a few things need to be taken into consideration. After sending the delete via the web service all entries / keys in the pool are deleted instantly.

The Movilizer Cloud will remove the pool by using a cleanup worker which runs approx every 4 days, when resources are available though. And it will only remove the pool psyhically if it was empty for 90 days. That means that even so the pool is empty it can still be visible in the Portal until the cleanup worker deletes it completely when it stayed empty for 90 days. The 90 days are the current setting for the worker ... this can change sooner or later, but for now this is the value.

```
<masterdataPoolUpdate pool="yourPool">
    <delete />
</masterdataPoolUpdate>
```